# Showing QgsDebugMsg in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: pyqgis, eclipse, debugging

In the source code of QGIS, I see a lot of  QgsDebugMsg lines.

What should I do in order to show it when debug/run my standalone application in Eclipse PyDev?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you mean for "show messages in eclipse-pydev".

Generally speaking, as you can see in the code, QgsDebugMsg is a define that use QgsLogger, and QgsLogger documentation says:

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLogger.html#details

that you can use QGIS_DEBUG (level 0,1,2,3) and QGIS_DEBUG_FILE env vars to generate log file

Comment: What I meant by that was I have those lines in my code, but when I run in debug mode, I do not see them in my console output. So I was wondering if there is any settings I need to do in order to show these debug messages.

Comment: not in console but in the shell where you launch qgis... or if configured it will be redirect to a fiel set in QGIS_DEBUG_FILE env